Autodesk viewer dark edges when zooming out
When using Forge viewer and zooming out the model shows a lot of thick dark edges. Is it possible to tweak their appearance? I’m applying a theming color to the the model.
I’ve tried:

disabling edges but that’s too much
changing quality settings


Can you provide a picture of what you are seeing? Do you get that with all your files? The Revit model here seems ok https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/yLBdWmm
